# use json object with inner objects to android application

Tags: android, json

This is my json code from url.this objects not have  a general objects name but `{H0...H20}`each containing 5 childs that `imgtitle` and `imgtext` too include tow childs.

```
{  
"h0":{     
  "  id  ": 1092,  
" imgtitle ":  {"fa":"cc","en":"dd"},  
" imgtext ": {"fa_IR":"zz","en_GB":""},    
" url": "www.example.com"  
     }

"h1":{  
" id ":20221,  
" imgtitle ":{"fa":"","en":"example"},  
" imgtext ":{"fa_IR":"bb","en_GB":""},  
 " url ":"www.example.com" 
      }

      .
      .

"h20" {...
        }
}
```

my problem is
This code does not work. how fix it? and
What can I do if it works for `imgtitle` and `imgtext`??

```
 private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
       private ProgressDialog pDialog;
      @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
                  uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
                  myurl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.url);

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");

      }
      @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;

      }
       @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
         pDialog.dismiss();
         try {


       JSONObject myobject = new JSONObject("h0");

         int id = myobject.getInt("id");
         String myurl= myobject.getString("url");

            uid.setText(""+id);
            myurl.setText(myurl);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what isn't working but you should try out the Gson conversion library, it automates all this.

Comment: please don't write code shortcuts, try to make your code as readable as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the correct jsonObject, have a look at your code...myObject is new json..so of course it will he empty. You should use
`json.getJsonObject(h4)`. I'm answering using mobile so sorry about typos and formatting

Comment: JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject("h0");  
         
         String id = c.getString("id");

         JSONObject hh= c.getJSONObject("imgtitle");
         String ff=hh.getString("fa_IR");